# Django password and authentication for non standard users

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have been asked to introduce an unusual case and I'm wondering how others would go about it.

I have users in my Django application. The model is a standard user model, authentication. etc. Each one of of these site users can add  their own contacts to the system. However my new requirement is to allow their contacts to set a password (if they want to to) so that they can login to their status page (belonging to that user).

So my question is how would you do this? I already have the contact table (which belongs to one user), I'm thinking of adding in a password (optional) field, but then I'm unsure how to handle the authentication for this as they are not my users but members of my users (if that make sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create another user model for contacts inheriting from [`AbstractBaseUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser). And then [creating custom auth backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/) that would look in both models to login user. Finaly you would have to distinguish between standard user and contact user before every action. 
That is if contact user and standard user differ significantly in your application.

Or you could just create [custom user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) in your application, that would contain `is_contact` attribute. This would be used for both types of users. You would set that as `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings and check before every action for the `is_contact` attribute to determine the outcome. You could return 403 for the contact user if he tries to access what he's not suppose to.

Or if you use permissions in your application, you could set the contact user's persmissions only to view statuses of the users that added him as a contact and nothing else.